# No Json serializer found for type Seq[(String, String)]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.2

I want to convert a `Seq[(String, String)]` into  JSON with Scala play, but I face this error:

> No Json serializer found for type Seq[(String, String)]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. Say you have a `Seq[(String, String)]` like this:

```
val tuples = Seq(("z", "x"), ("v", "b"))
```

If you are trying to serialize it as following:

```
{
  "z" : "x",
  "v" : "b"
}
```

Then just use `Json.toJson(tuples.toMap)`. If you'd like to have some custom representation of your tuples you can define a `Writes` as the compiler suggests:

```
implicit val writer = new Writes[(String, String)] {
  def writes(t: (String, String)): JsValue = {
    Json.obj("something" -> t._1 + ", " + t._2)
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._

class MyController extends Controller {
  implicit val writer = new Writes[(String, String)] {
    def writes(t: (String, String)): JsValue = {
      Json.obj("something" -> t._1 + ", " + t._2)
    }
  }

  def myAction = Action { implicit request =>
    val tuples = Seq(("z", "x"), ("v", "b"))
    Ok(Json.toJson(tuples))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response serejja, but I want to know how to prepare my controller to serialize the Seq[(String,String)] in json format.

Comment: give me more details please

Comment: @lotfitounsi please see my edited answer. This should work fine

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serialize Scala tuples into 2-element JSON arrays (this is pretty common), then you can write an implicit Writes object for the general case of a 2-Tuple (A, B). This will handle your case of (String, String) as well as any other combination of types!

```
implicit def tuple2Writes[A, B](implicit w1: Writes[A], w2: Writes[B]): Writes[(A, B)] = new Writes[(A, B)] {
  def writes(tuple: (A, B)) = JsArray(Seq(w1.writes(tuple._1), w2.writes(tuple._2)))
}
```

If you place this in a package object, it will be visible to the entire package. That's a nice way to get consistent behavior across many classes (i.e. an entire application).